# Andorid - Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: android, selenium

I am trying to execute below code in Android WebDriver. But consistently i am facing the below issue -  "Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died / Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond"

Any help will be a great help. Thanks in advance

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver;


public class PayTM {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.paytm.com");
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

}

}
```

Error Stack :-

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
    Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
    System info: host: 'B91326', ip: '10.248.175.97', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
    Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:276)
        at PayTM.main(PayTM.java:11)
    Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:223)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:337)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:298)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
        ... 2 more
```

Comment: I doubt you'll get much support, the AndroidDriver is deprecated. Use something like Appium.

Comment: `The target server failed to respond` - have you started the selenium server on android device? [Reference](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Using_the_Remote_Server)